# find the nearest time for all times in a column

Tags: r, time

I have a column ("timestamp2") including 66 times and want to find the nearest time for each time, and then calculate the time interval for these two times.

[image]

For example, the first time in the column "timestamp2" is "2020-08-18 18:15:37", the nearest time to this time should be "2020-08-18 18:15:44" and the time interval between these two times should be 6 seconds.

There are many solutions to the problem of finding the closest time for a given time in a time column. My question is a little different as it requires searching within the given column and needs to require the time and time interval.

Comment: hello, can you use `dput` on a sample of your data to make this [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: please provide your data in a reusable format.

Comment: Maybe something like: `x <- as.POSIXct(c("2020-08-18 18:15:37", "2020-08-18 18:15:44", "2020-08-18 18:15:50")); lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) min(abs(x[i] - x[-i])))`

Comment: do you need the answer for SQL (TSQL?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could e.g. use `order` and `diff`:

```
DF <- data.frame(i = 1:66, timestamp2 = Sys.time()-runif(66, min = 1, max = 100))
DF <- DF[order(DF$timestamp2),]
DF$timediff <- c(NA_real_, diff(DF$timestamp2))
```

---

```
    i          timestamp2     timediff
64 64 2020-09-02 15:11:47           NA
65 65 2020-09-02 15:11:48 1.1161799431
58 58 2020-09-02 15:11:52 3.4341783524
13 13 2020-09-02 15:11:53 1.0964329243
5   5 2020-09-02 15:11:55 2.0064251423
59 59 2020-09-02 15:11:55 0.0007073879
```

---

Or if you just want the resulting vector: `diff(sort(DF$timestamp2))`